# Avoid container div

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Say you have a website and have a fancy pink header which stretches all across your screen horizontal. Inside the header there some text which needs to be centered and have a 960px fixed width area.

```
---------------------------
|   x   |  hello   |   x   |
|                          |
|   y   |  hi      |   y   |
---------------------------
```

x = pink background row
y = yellow background row

Does someone has an up to date css (no js) solution to dismiss the need of a container div just often for padding?

html:

```
<header>
    <div>
        hello
   </div>
</header>
<footer>
    <div>
        hi
   </div>
</footer>
```

css:

```
header {
  background: pink;
}
header > div {
  width: 960px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Does someone has a solution, maybe something with pseudo before and after?
So you can just write beautiful html:

```
<header>hello</header>
<footer>hi</footer>
```

and fix it all in css.

This is a basic example, the point is; I am often bound to use a div just for layout things, mostly padding. Of course I can set seperate background to do the trick, but I am talking about keeping this all together, since, the  probably has the same issue and another background. And same with the main content, and so on.

Wish there was something like:

```
header{
  background: pink;
  padding: 100%-960px;
}
```

That would 'do the trick' and scales after resizing the viewport.

Comment: Edit: Sorry post was scrabbled a bit at first post. (Markdown regex required an empty linefeed before a code block I found out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically I would just use multiple container divs, with a container class...  Like hellow and hi would both be in a div with "wrapper class", and x and y would both be 100% width wrapper-of-wrapper divs.

But since your goal is to avoid wrapper divs... then I won't go into detail about how you can accomplish this with 4 wrapper divs :)

I think you should look into these links:

- http://sass-lang.com/
- http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#less

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah that's how I do it now, just write a wrapper class on 960px and reuse it at all container divs. But like I said there are also many situations, like side bars where you need a fixed width content and a fixed width background... (I don't see what less or sasc has to do with this.). Would be cool if there's a new css property "container-width", that would be ultra handy.